# What is the difference between (., .., ...) in html file path?

Tags: html, path

So my question is what is the difference between.

. 
.. 
...

I know `..` goes up 1 directory. And `.` I think is used for current directory but I don't know what the <kbd>...</kbd> is for. Can anyone tell me?

Comment: That depends on where you are seeing it. The only time I have seen a directory named `...` was when somebody hacked a server and hid a bunch of files in that directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From empirical testing with my own webserver, there's nothing special about `...`

It is simply a valid directory name which can exist under my web root directory.

However, like `..` and `.` and all other paths in Unix that start with a `.`, **it is not shown** when one runs the command `ls` instead of `ls -a`.

Note: As @EdCottrell mentioned, it is a somewhat suspicious choice of directory name, so it might be the symptom of an attack.

Comment: Oh okay. I'll just mark that as answer then. THanks for your testing/time.

Comment: This answer is correct, but as I said in my comment above, it's a very strange - and suspicious - name for a directory.